# Boolean no Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Tenho uma classe no Angular chamada usuário que recebe 2 campos boolean

```js
export class UsuariosModel {
    UsuarioId: Number;
    Nome: string;
    Sobrenome: string;
    Email: string;
    Senha: string;
    Corretor: boolean;
    Contrato: boolean;   
}
```

Na minha pagina eu tenho um formulário usando o formGroup e com todos esses campos, sendo o 'Corretor' e o 'Contrato' do 'type:checkbox'. da seguinte maneira...

```html
<form [formGroup]="formUser" novalidate>
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input formControlName="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome" />

    <label>Sobrenome</label>
    <input formControlName="sobrenome" type="text" placeholder="Sobrenome" />

    <label>Email</label>
    <input formControlName="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />

    <label>Senha</label>
    <input formControlName="senha" type="text" placeholder="senha" />

    <label>corretor</label>
    <input formControlName="corretor" type="checkbox" />

    <label>Contrato</label>
    <input formControlName="contrato" type="checkbox" />

    <button (click)="inserindoUsuario(formUser.value)">Criar</button>
</form>
```

No meu TypeScript dessa pagina, eu tenho um método que cria um objeto do tipo 'Usuário' e recebe os parâmetros do formGroup. Porém se eu não check o checkbox ele vem vazio dessa forma 'contrato:""', e não como false dessa forma 'contrato:false'...

Aqui está meu FormGroup e meu método...

***FormGroup***

```js
constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private api: ChamadaApi, http: Http){
    this.Http = http;

    this.formUser = fb.group({
        nome: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        sobrenome: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        senha: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        corretor: new FormControl(''),
        contrato: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
}
```

***Método***

```js
inserindoUsuario(usuarios: any){
    this.usuariosModel = {
         UsuarioId: null,
         Nome: usuarios.nome,
         Sobrenome: usuarios.sobrenome,
         Email: usuarios.email,
         Senha: usuarios.senha,
         Corretor: usuarios.corretor,
         Contrato: usuarios.contrato
     }

     this.api.CreateUser(this.usuariosModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As aspas no FormControl são a inicialização se você deixar como aspas ele vai achar que e string tenta setar como false no inicio

```
 corretor: new FormControl(false),
 contrato: new FormControl(false, [Validators.required]),
```

Comment: Booooa, perfeito, funcionou perfeitamente...